# Material Component for web in AngularDart

Tags: material-design, material-ui, angular-dart, material-components

How can I use the Modular and customizable Material Design UI components for the web in my angular-dart project?
https://material.io/components/
I particularly want to use Typography, So can any one tell me how can I do that.

Thank You

Comment: I have an open source project aiming to get this done, but for now, it only has a few components. PR's are welcome. I want to use this in a new project, so hopefully I'll be more active on it these days: https://github.com/mdc-dart/material_components_web

Comment: Thanks, Tobe your suggestion can work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ship a set of high quality AngularDart components as part of this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/angular_components

We don't yet expose Typography as part of this package, though.

Are there any specific features you're looking for?

Comment: We have some typography styles here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/src/css/material/const/_typography.scss

They are not part of the build process yet but I am actively working on including them so you can import them in your SASS files and use them in your projects.

Comment: ok I will have to learn using SASS files with the CSS, can you just estimate me a target time according to you till when the most of the components will be released for dart like other platforms have i.e. mdl for js and android platform have.